# Why ZFS ARC hit rate is higher than real performance hit?

Tags: cache, zfs, zfsonlinux, statistics

We've got `Debian Wheezy` host with `ZFS on Linux` with in.
It is used only for serving large files over `http`.
User activity is mostly characterized by a lot of random read.

We've noticed that `~95%` `ARC` hit rate 
gives us `~80 MByte/s` hdd reading activity
with the overall `~160 MByte/s` server output.

I've already checked `ARC` and `L2` `prefetch` options are disabled.
Linux read ahead for this array is set at default `512` and changing this value doesn't give any sensible effect.

What is the reason of such difference and is there any way to get proper statistic for real `ARC` usage?

Comment: What tools are you using to observe this?

Comment: @ewwhite atop, iostat and zpool iostat shows same results for hdd and network, arcstat.py and /proc/spl/kstat/zfs/arcstats for ARC performance.

Comment: What difference are you referring to?  If all the data is being served over your network, the network is likely limiting performance too.  What is the network hardware?

Comment: @AndrewHenle We've got Intel Corporation 82599EB 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ (interrupts are spread between cores - 1 irq per 1 core). If network is limited the reading speed should decrease when it meets buffer size, isn't it?

Comment: @AlexanderKlimenko Only if the filesystem and hardware is unable to keep up with the network transfer.  File read-ahead may allow slower hardware to mask delays by simply adding a bit of latency that you won't notice when sending a large file over the network.  The HTTP transfer over the network also may have latencies that allow your hardware to keep up.  How fast can you transfer data that's known to already be entirely in memory?

Comment: @AndrewHenle  We got some servers with 40gbit/s networks that serve files only from memory (with 99-100 arc git ratio) we are getting up to 16gbit/s and speed/connections ratio shows that it is not the limit. One of the ideas is that arc stores not only data but metadata too. May be metadata takes other part of those hits?